# How to introduce my villain in the prologue?

Tags: introduction, prologues, villain

I am currently doing a rewrite of my story, starting with the prologue. Now, my prologue exists mainly to introduce the main villain of the story, and I've been working on making some improvements, such as spreading the big bad's description across the prologue, rather than just simply dumping it all in one paragraph. The prologue introduced him playing chess, getting interrupted by someone begging him to help his associate, and ordered his guards to dispose of the interloper before returning to his game. However, I've had some criticisms such as the perspective being too objective, (I use 3rd person, and try to avoid 1st person), and a few other things. I know it'll never be perfect, but I at least want it to at least be more engaging.

Comment: I am not clear on what is being asked.  It sounds like you are making the right choices, but are still working on improving the immersive elements of your writing. What should I write kind of questions tend to get closed.

Comment: Concur with EDL. Is this a style question (e.g. about prologues) or technique question (how do I write it)? If style, then this is probably a duplicate of [When is a prologue useful](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/993/when-is-a-prologue-useful). If technique, then it's better suited to [Critique Circle](https://www.critiquecircle.com).

Answer (score 2):

### What are the Stakes?

Scenes are interesting because someone is taking a risk; I want something, but something else prevents me from getting it, so I take a risk, and a scene happens.

As you've described it, the villain is not taking any risks. They don't *want* anything. So the scene isn't engaging because the POV character isn't really engaged.

### The Petitioner's Risk

But the **Petitioner** wants something. And they are certainly taking a risk. Re-frame the scene around the Petitioner. Do they understand the risk they're taking? Why do they take it? How do they feel about it?

Seeing the Villain through the Petitioner's POV is probably going to show the readers a lot more of who the Villain really is, and it should be more fun.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this at all.

This doesn't sound like a prologue, but an opening scene.

That said, your structure is all wrong. Your opening scene should be hero oriented.

JK Rowling got away with a kludge in the first Harry Potter book (Sorcerer's Stone), introducing a lot of magical elements, but still focused on magicians saving the baby Harry Potter, whose magician parents were murdered, and placing him secretly in foster care with relatives where the killer would not find him. Chapter Two just jumps forward 10 years, to Harry's tenth birthday.

This was prologue presented as a scene; about the only way to do it, and it seems to be what you are trying to do. But the focus of Rowling's Chapter 1 is definitely all about Harry, the Hero readers are supposed to identify with.

The other adult magicians present in Chapter 1, like Dumbledore, are prominent characters we will see later. This helps introduce them. But no villains were depicted, except by reference. (Any villains would ruin the secrecy of where Harry was hidden away; clearly the main villain tried to kill Harry and failed.)

The person you focus on, in the first "chapter" or "prologue" or "background" or whatever that the audience sees, is going to be assumed as the focus of the entire story, the person the audience should follow.

Do not make that the villain.

I'd strongly recommend not writing a prologue at all. Stories typically open, for the first 10% to 15% of the story, on the hero and their "Normal Life" *before* some triggering event happens that upsets that normal life. (AKA the "inciting incident".)

The rest of the work is focused on the escalation of the problems caused by that inciting incident, etc.

In Rowling's first Harry Potter book, we can see that pattern starting in Chapter 2 (not 1, the disguised prologue), on Harry's 10th birthday, when strange magical things start to happen to Harry, and finally Hagrid the giant comes pounding on the front door to collect Harry and escort him to Hogwart's.

The inciting incident is Harry's birthday, he has come of age to start his formal wizarding school, and we the audience are introduced vicariously through the naive Harry to a world of nearly constant magic everywhere all the time.

If you want to introduce your villain early from the villain's POV, change viewpoints for your Chapter 2. You don't have to alternate, but this is the "natural" way for the audience to experience the villain.

Hero POV first, Villain POV second.

You can alternate, or not, you can primarily focus on the Hero, but switch once in a while to the Villain POV. You are not necessarily trying to tell the Villain's story, but you might switch when the Hero first does something to attract the Villain's attention, like thwart a plan the Villain had, to piss off the Villain.

This is a harder story to write; but Stephen King does it, e.g. in The Stand. 007 Movies do it frequently. But it is a bit harder because when you focus on the Villain, the audience expects to be privy to the Villain's decisions and strategic moves, and will feel "cheated" if the author fails to show Villain scenes where crucial decisions and/or mistakes are made by the Villain, and those in turn must be well justified.

I think you could just as easily demonstrate your Villain's psychopathic disregard for life either indirectly (the Hero discovers a village with slaughtered children or something), or from the Hero POV: The Hero watches helplessly while the Villain kills people mercilessly.

I would not open your story on the Villain. Best selling authors like Stephen King or Rowling or Dan Brown with a huge guaranteed audience might get away with that. Publisher's trust them to know what they are doing and trust the audience to buy their stories sight unseen.

Amateurs hoping to get published for the first time should stick to the script. Obviously new authors are getting published all the time; but publishers tend to want to minimize as much risk as possible on new authors. They want to see a new story with great writing and strong characters and scenes **but** in a very familiar *structure* that they know *works*.

Comment: Minor nitpicks, here, but Chapter 2 of HP Book 1 isn't Harry's Birthday, but Dudley's (they go to the zoo, the snake escapes and talks to Harry).  Chapter 3 ends with Harry counting down to Midnight on his Birthday, which is the focus of Chapter 4 and 5.

Comment: @hszmv +1, I haven't read it in a decade or so!

Comment: I haven't either.  I just remembered Chapter 2 was the snake thing.  I actually started listening to the Audio Book for the sixth book (as I didn't binge the last two books as much as I did the first five when I read them as a kid) and the fact that Dudley is a month older than Harry was brought up in that one.

Comment: There are certainly books that open with the villain's actions.  Indeed, there are many stories that start with what turns out to be a minor character, who is killed to kick off the story.  There is no fixed rule that you must start with the hero.

Comment: @Mary As I said, ***amateurs*** should stick to the script if they want to maximize their chances of getting published. The "script", in novels and screenplays, is basically the Three Act Structure, sticking to the average word count of their genre (or page count in scripts), sticking to the correct font size and margins and typeface and coloring within the lines on every other aspect. The point is to provide a clear picture of one's writing ability and imagination. It's not just one story, publishers & producers want to sign a talent. Improvisation can come later, after trust is built.

Comment: Only things that stick out from the slushpile get published.   Harming the story to fit the script makes a story very run of the mill.

Comment: @Mary We will disagree. Things stick out from the slushpile (in a positive way) because of writing ability and authorial imagination. First time authors have no record. They have no fans. They can add little to nothing to promoting their work, other than going to bookstores to sell in person, which they may suck at too: Many authors are not very sociable or confident or engaging when speaking to strangers. We don't become authors because we are great sales people. If you can't write a good first story while "sticking to the script", it is unlikely to sell. Innovate when you have lots of fans.

Comment: @Amadeus You're not wrong, just too pragmatic. Not the advice I would want to have given an undiscovered Susanna Clarke. Write for your passion. First and last and always. That is how you will do your best writing: with curiosity and determination and love and ferocity and defiance, if need be. Don't take my word for it; so sayeth every commencement address ever.

Comment: @kmunky  Rowling also didn't follow that advice.